# List if items displayed in scroll pane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have objects stored in HasMap with keys as Strings, where registration number of the car is the key in a map.

Map cars = new HashMap<>();

Now I want to display all keys from the map in a Scroll Pane where user can select registration number of the Car. The question is how to display the keys of Car from the map in a Scroll Pane box? 
Should I add jList to Scroll Pane and then loop through the Map keys adding each String from the Key to jList?

Comment: Please tell the important details and show the relevant [mcve] code so that your question is more understandable.  Please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to learn more of how to improve your questions.

Comment: please show us what you've tried

Comment: "*Should I add jList to Scroll Pane and then loop ...?*" Yes, you are on the right track.

Comment: `Should I add jList to Scroll Pane and then loop through the Map keys adding each String from the Key to jList?` - sounds reasonable, although you may want the keys to be added in sorted order to make each key easier to find in the JList.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the the keys from the hashmap like below.once you have got the key you can get the particular value Associated with the key.

```
Map cars = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> keys=cars.keySet();
for(String key:keys){
    System.out.println(cars.get(key));
}
```